# What is a better approach than trigger

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table say TAB1 in oracle 11g database which is huge and transactional in nature,update and insert happens regularly.Any new record generated/updated needs to reach downstream applications.The existing approach was to replicate this data in this table to a SQL server table and some other application (messaging application used to pick it from there).They want to move away from this approach.

So the suggestion from us was to create (insert and update trigger on this table TAB1  ),thus those specific records gets replicated based on those triggers into a staging table (this staging table is in oracle itself) and messaging application picks up from staging table.

We need these records to flow immediately ( a slight delay is acceptable ) but it cant wait the whole day and batch it and messaged.

Issue:- DBA's are not agreeing with the trigger approach

Question:-
1.Is there any issue in using triggers in oracle
2.Any better approach to avoid triggers ?

Comment: How huge is "huge"?

Comment: @Littefoot The records are in millions

Comment: Well, if DBAs won't allow triggers, see whether you can create a stored procedure which would select those records, move them into the staging table and do the processing *regularly* (for example, every 5 minutes) using a **database job** (see DBMS_SCHEDULER and/or its *older brother* DBMS_JOB packages for more info).